# Adding attributes to OutTable of Check Geometry tool using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I am writing a script that checks the geometry of all point, lines and polygons in a gdb. I used a script provided by Esri and it works fine, however it only returns the name of the featureclass, object Id and problem.

I would also like it to return a specific attribute of each feature with a geometry problem; Namely "PUIcode"

I used the following script:

```
# The geodatabase in which the feature classes will be checked
source_gdb = r"C:\Users\deboerr7373\Documents\assets.gdb"
outTable = "checkGeometryResult"

# A variable that will hold the list of all the feature classes 
# inside the geodatabase
def listFcsInGDB(gdb):  
    ''' list all Feature Classes in a geodatabase, including inside Feature Datasets ''' 
    arcpy.env.workspace = source_gdb  
    fcs = []  
    for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('','feature') + ['']:  
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('', 'point' or 'line' or 'polygon' ,fds):  
            fcs.append(os.path.join(fds, fc))  
    return fcs  

fcs = listFcsInGDB(source_gdb)

print("Running the check geometry tool on {} feature classes".format(len(fcs)))
arcpy.CheckGeometry_management(fcs, outTable)

print("{} geometry problems found, see {} for details.".format(arcpy.GetCount_management(outTable)[0],
                                                               outTable))
```

And I got the following results "CheckGeometryResult": 
[image]

However What I would like to have: 
[image]

The data in my bdg are point/line/polygon feature classes and have the following attributes: 
[image]

Has anyone any idea how to solve this problem? 
I considered joining tables afterwards, however the CheckGeometryResult table contains objects id's that come from different features classes. So I would than have to join on the combination of featureclass name and object Id. But I could only find the option of joining on only object Id.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simple case of running your code in a different order.

Run the check geometry individually rather than supplying a list of featureclasses to test. This way you can join the PUICode to the output table on each run.